# Paypal refund between 2 users

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

At the moment, I have PHP code which allows user1 to pay user2.  If user2 logs into his/her paypal account s/he will see a `refund` button next to the transaction for 60 days.

If user2 clicks the `refund` button, is it possible for my PHP code to capture and/or receive details about this refund event, even though all this is happening directly from the paypal site?

I'm guessing this is not possible, but am posting this question with the thought that I could be wrong as I don't know paypal's api's like the back of my hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the location of your IPN listener to your account settings. This way, all notifications will be sent to your listener regardless of whether it initiates from your code. At paypal.com, specify the Notification URL to your IPN listener in the Profile > My Selling Tools section of your PayPal Business or Premier account.

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/ht_ipn
https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/ES/es_ES/files/developer/IPNGuide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by setting up a listener on your website for paypal IPN.

https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNReference

Comment: I have an ipn listener already which works nicely for receiving payments from user1 to user2 as long as they initiate the payment from my php code.  The refund is initiated directly from the user2's paypal account.  I have just tried a refund, and absolutely nothing was returned to my ipn file.  I understand how to make use of the ipn system if the user2 refunds user1 using my php code, but i don't understand how to make use of ipn if user2 does the refund directly from the paypal website.